# Online Masters in the US without GRE and TOEFL

Tags: masters, united-states, gre, toefl

I am a full-time Software Development Engineer and am looking to pursue Masters in Computer Science through an online learning program from a reasonably reputed University. Georgia Tech's OMS came very close to what I was looking for, but I do not have TOEFL, which is a requirement (I don't qualify for a waiver). I wanted to know if there are any other options out  there which offer online medium of instruction and do not have a requirement GRE and TOEFL?

Comment: Tuition at American universities is in English. It seems very unlikely that any reputable program would accept a student who can't demonstrate that they understand English. Obviously, one can't be sure from five lines of text but your English looks excellent to me -- can't you just take the TOEFL exam?

Comment: TOEFL might be quite an expensive way to prove your English skills. Some universities also allow other ways to show it, e.g. a certificate about language classes taken at your university. You might want to contact the university in the US about what they accept.

Comment: @Bemte A TOEFL is still much cheaper than a Master from a less reputed university, just because one had no TOEFL

Comment: @Bemte I checked with them and TOEFL is a requirement, also the cut off is 100/120 for OMS. I was a little surprised that they had such a stringent cut off on a program offered through the MOOC format. I mean, I've done MOOCs before and I had no trouble understanding the professor or interacting with others with my English. But yeah, that's probably another topic.

Comment: @Greg I agree. I am going to give TOEFL a shot. After all, I can only make it to Spring 2018 now.

Comment: Just wanted to add that I got through TOEFL, made 117/120. Going for the next steps to make it into 2018 Jan batch :)